# FragmentTransaction replace() method only replacing some elements in layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop

So I have an activity handling fragment transcations to replace different layouts. I initially have my login fragment layout replaced in within the method onCreated(), then I try and replace it with my maps fragment layout when the login fragment calls the listener method in my activity. My login layout appears fine but when I switch to the maps layout, half of the login buttons and fields are still on the screen overlapping the maps activity. Is there a hole in my container or something?

Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_layo);
    fm = getFragmentManager();
    if (lf == null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            lf = (LoginFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("Login");
            return;
        }
    }
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    lf = new LoginFragment();
    ft.replace(R.id.mainContainer, lf);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}

@Override
public void onLogIn(String sessionID) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    MapScreenFragment mapFrag = new MapScreenFragment();
    ft.replace(R.id.loginpage, mapFrag);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

fragment_login:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="login.shogun.comet.halp.LoginFragment"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/loginpage"
android:weightSum="1"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@color/halp1Color">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/Username"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/HalpLogo" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/Password"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/username"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/username"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

LoginFragment is set to:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
```

fragment_map:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/map">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_map" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fakeMarker"
    android:src="@drawable/student_turq"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/fakeMarker"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MapScreenFragment is set to:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
```

I cut out a bunch of buttons for brevity sake, and I also have logic in between setting the content view in my activity and changing the fragment that has also been taken out for brevity.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace using the same container. Try change the 2nd replace to `R.id.mainContainer`.

```
 FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    lf = new LoginFragment();
    ft.replace(R.id.mainContainer, lf); <-----
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
@Override
public void onLogIn(String sessionID) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    MapScreenFragment mapFrag = new MapScreenFragment();
    ft.replace(R.id.loginpage, mapFrag); <------ change to R.id.mainContainer
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Another easy solution would be to set the background color of your fragment_map's main RelativeLayout to white color.

Comment: So the second replace should be replace(lf,mapFrag)? Because the first argument has to be a container id.

Comment: should be like ft.replace(R.id.mainContainer, mapFrag), it's like saying you want to replace the content of 'mainContainer' with mapFrag.